# Кастомизация tljh

Tags: linux, ubuntu, интерфейс

Нужна помощь с тем как можно сделать кастомизацию интерфейса TLJH( изменить логотип, изменить цвет интерфейса и тд). работаю с ubuntu и linux.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: с помощью tljh можно создать свой сервер и у него нужно изменить цвет фона и логотип

Comment: Ну а ты пробовал поискать png файлы в установленном пакете?